# Coordinates of csv file not showing in required location

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.2

I have csv file like this:

[image: CSV]

I want to plot these places in a map. I have added these coordinates with the help of google earth and tried to plot these coordinates in both QGIS and ArcMap. But, the location is showing in different place than the actual location. How can I solve it?

In QGIS,the x field is longitude and yfield is latitude  and the CRS is EPSG 4326.

Comment: I plotted the first point ("Place" = Balaju), and it was on the outskirts of Katmandu, about a kilometer southeast of Raniban Forest. Is that where it's supposed to be?

Comment: How far off are your points?  Maybe you do not have enough significant digits at this latitude?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be in the right places.

[image: Kathmandu]

I used Add Delimited Text Layer in QGIS 2.18